# Not able start windows .bat file with node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
async function testprocess()
{ 
  console.log('in side testprocess..')
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  ls    = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'c:/Magic xpi 4.13.5/Runtime/MgxpiCmdl.bat']);
  
  ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });
  
  ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  });
  
  ls.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
  });
console.log('End of testprocess..')
}
```

OUTPUT:

in side testprocess..
End of testprocess..
stdout: [MgxpiCmdl] start with arguments []

stderr: The system cannot find the path specified.

stdout: [MgxpiCmdl] done

child process exited with code 0

If any one has any idea about this please suggest.

I have used below link for reference

[Run a bat file from node.js](https://singhak.in/run-a-bat-file-from-node-js-execute-child-process-from-node-js/)

Comment: This code isn't running a .bat file. It's running `cmd`, with arguments that make _that_ run something called `magic` with a bunch of run option. So, two questions: (1) why are you wrapping things in `cmd` instead of just running the application that you need to run, and (2) what is `magic`? (and then on a sidenote: your async function will return before the actual spawned process competes. That seems almost certainly not what you want)

Comment: Hello @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the quick response, I am trying to do same thing which is mentioned in this link => https://singhak.in/run-a-bat-file-from-node-js-execute-child-process-from-node-js/

Comment: I'm not clicking that: please [edit] your post to [include all the details](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Seriously: it's probably been a while so please reread the posting guidelines over [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask) because you're just not giving the details folks need to help: you're running a command (node) that runs a command (cmd) that runs a command (magic) that runs a bat file. But only maybe because we don't know what "magic" is (put that in your post). So what debugging did you do already? Does the command work when you run it outside of node? Please update your post to include all the details: if the rest of the web goes down, your post should still make sense.